# How to tune camel kafka throughput?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

In my camel application I have a simple route consuming from one kafka topic, setting only some headers in a simple Processor, and sending the exchange to some other kafka topic:

```
.from(kafka:startTopic).process(new HeaderEnrichter).to(kafka:endTopic)
```

I am using the default camel threading.
My messages are between **1Kb and 3Kb**. For kafka, I am using the default values for consumer (polling) and producer (batching). 
For 1 partition and a machine with 16GB RAM, I observe that only around **100msg/seconds** can be send to one topic.

I tried to increase **max poll records** and **batching size**, but it didn't increase throughput. 
I am wondering, which parameters/strategies to look at in order to generate higher throughput? I expected that > 5000/msg should be possible?

Comment: do you have any asnwer for this yet?

Comment: We found out that kafka producer did not send batches in this case, even when batch size is increased. You have to give him a batch, for example by putting an aggregator between from and to. This increased throughput a lot for us (factor 10).

Comment: We run into a few problems with exchange header after adding aggregation. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363673/how-to-forward-kafka-headers-of-aggregated-exchanges.